# MongoDB: Approach for storing frequently modified references

Tags: database-design, mongodb

Need a piece of advice for storing a large number of references between Mongo entities that are frequently updated.

**Some background**:

- 1 event can have 5000 logs.
- 1 event can have 10 assets associated (assignment object).
- Logs are created per asset per event.
- Query pattern: find all logs by assignment (eventId and assetId).

**Entities with their relations**:

```
EVENT <-1--------------N-> LOG   
EVENT <-N--ASSIGNMENT--N-> ASSET
```

**Mongo collections and documents**:

```
event: { id, name, ... }
asset: { id, name, ... }
log: { id, eventId, metadata, ... }
assignment: { id, assetId, eventId, metadata, ... }
```

## Here comes the **question**:

- What is the best way to store associations between logs and assignments (events and assets)? Note that those associations are updated **frequently and concurrently**.

### **Approach 1**

Store logIds in assignment entity:

```
assignment: { id, assetId, eventId, logIds, ... }
```

### **Approach 2**

Create a separate entity for holding a single reference between log and assignment:

```
assignmentLog: { assignmentId, logId }
```

---

**Another approach ?**

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to understand your question, logs and assignments are directly related to events with 1 to N mapping, Assets are directly related to assignments with 1 to N mapping. `{"eventId":1,"logs":[{"logId":1},{"logId":2},{"logId":3},{"logId":4},{"logId":5}],"assignments":[{"assigmentId":1,"assets":[{"assetId":11},{"assetId":12},{"assetId":13},{"assetId":14}]},{"assigmentId":2,"assets":[{"assetId":21},{"assetId":22},{"assetId":23},{"assetId":24}]},{"assigmentId":3,"assets":[{"assetId":31},{"assetId":32},{"assetId":33},{"assetId":34}]}]}` Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Correct. But there is one more relation: asset<-1—N->log. And I am thinking what is the best way to store those relations. Note that asset logs is a subset of event logs. For example: event1 has [log1, log2, log3] and event1 is assigned to [asset1, asset2]. At the same time event1-asset1 can have [log1, log2] and event1-asset2 can have just [log3]. Hope it is more clear now :)

Comment: Please have a look at these bast practices https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3